# How to optimize recursive permutation algorithm for all 4x4 "magic squares"

Tags: python

A "magic square" consists of an n x n matrix where the rows, columns, and diagonals all equal a constant. For 4 x 4 magic squares, that constant is 34. I'm attempting to optimize my permutation algorithm, which currently lists all possible 4 x 4 matrices using digits ranging from 1-16, to skip over certain permutations if the current matrix doesn't match the magic square criteria.

I already have the recursive algorithm to permute all combinations. This function takes a length 16 array, which is representative of the square, and prints all possible combinations that fit the "magic" criteria. I'm not sure how to implement a check in the recursive call to optimize it though. For example, I want it so that if the first row of the matrix doesn't sum up to 34, skip that permutation and proceed to the next one (and so on and so forth for the proceeding rows).

```
def permute(a, lo, hi):
    if(lo == hi) and (isMagic(a)):
        print(a)
    else:
        for i in range(lo, hi):
            # this is where I imagine the exceptions would be made
            a[lo], a[i] = a[i], a[lo]
            permute4(a, lo + 1, hi, count, n)
            a[lo], a[i] = a[i], a[lo]
```

When removing the "isMagic" check, which simply prints all combinations, including those that arent "magic", it takes a painfully long time for the function to print the squares. I ultimately would like to speed this up by excluding unnecessary permutations. How would I implement this check?

Comment: Apologies, perhaps I'm not strong enough in my maths skills.  "an n x n matrix where the rows, columns, and diagonals all equal a constant" - what function are you applying to the rows, columns, and diagonals cell values, to produce the constant?

Comment: What do you want help with? You are using a function `permute4` which is not defined. It would help if you could provide a runnable example, that clearly explain your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to depend on already generated cells. For example you never need to generate a 4-element permutation, because you know that their sum is 34, thus the 4th element even in the first row has to be `34-sum(first 3 elements)`. If such element never existed (like `1,2,3,28`), or is already in use (like `1,3,15,15`), that attempt will not work and you can proceed to the next one without generating the rest of the table. In fact the first two element can already create an upper/lower limit for the remaining ones, for example `1,2` means that the remaining two elements will be `15` and `16`. One may pre-generate/filter all the individual permutations having the sum of 34, and pick candidates based on what is already there in the square.
Another trick is connected to this one: if you always generate rows, you always try a lot of things, 3+1 brand new elements. However if you generate a column after having a row in place, you are dealing with a 2-element permutation only (because the first element is known and the last one is calculated).

Example implementation (without pre-generation):

```
import itertools,time

def check(attempt):
  for i in range(0,4):
    if sum(attempt[i*4:i*4+4]) != 34:
      return False
    if sum(attempt[i+j*4] for j in range(0,4)) != 34:
      return False
  if sum(attempt[i+i*4] for i in range(0,4)) != 34:
    return False
  if sum(attempt[3-i+i*4] for i in range(0,4)) != 34:
    return False
  return True

def row(pos,field,rest):
  base=34-sum(field[pos*4:pos*4+pos])
  for p in itertools.permutations(rest,3-pos):
    r=base-sum(p)
    s=rest-set(p)
    if r in s:
      for i in range(pos,3):
        field[pos*4+i]=p[i-pos]
      field[pos*4+3]=r
      column(pos,field,s-{r})

count = 0

def column(pos,field,rest):
  if len(rest) == 0:
    if check(field):
      global count
      count+=1
      print("{} {}".format(count,field))
    return
  base=34-sum([field[pos+4*i] for i in range(0,pos+1)])
  for p in itertools.permutations(rest,2-pos):
    r=base-sum(p)
    s=rest-set(p)
    if r in s:
      for i in range(pos+1,3):
        field[pos+i*4]=p[i-pos-1]
      field[pos+4*3]=r
      row(pos+1,field,s-{r})

start=time.time()

row(0,[0]*16,set(range(1,17)))

print(time.time()-start)
```

It generates the 7040 solutions in 1-2 minutes (61 seconds on my machine, but it is a relatively new one). It is probably correct, as [880](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Number_of_magic_squares_of_a_given_order) unique solutions are expected, but this code generates the rotated and mirrored squares too (7040=8*880).
Actually the implementation of `check()` is overly cautious: because of the generation method it is enough to check the diagonals (the `for` loop with the two `if`-s can be removed).